# Atmosphere request.onOpen never gets called. Client-Server connection stopped showing: "101 switching protocols"

Tags: rest, jersey, jetty, mule, atmosphere

I have downloaded the "atmosphere-chat" (jersey) and modified a little because I wanted it to be running inside Jetty.
Everithing is working on this side (in stand alone way). Atmosphere 2.2.0-RC3 / Jetty jetty-9.2.0.M1

But when I put those inside Mule the request.onOpen is never called. 
Here is the piece of javascript code (I didn't change from the example):

```
var request = { url: 'http://myIP:8080/sc.eco/servlet/chat/',
                contentType : "application/json",
                logLevel : 'debug',
                transport : 'websocket' ,
                trackMessageLength : true,
                fallbackTransport: 'long-polling'};


request.onOpen = function(response) {
    content.html($('<p>', { text: 'Atmosphere connected using ' + response.transport }));
    input.removeAttr('disabled').focus();
    status.text('Choose name:');
};
```

It's shown on the console "Websocket successfully opened":
[image]
but it's stacked in this request:

```
Request URL:ws://myIP:8080/sc.eco/servlet/chat/?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.1-jquery&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-Cache-Date=0&Content-Type=application/json&X-atmo-protocol=true
Request Method:GET
Status Code:101 Switching Protocols
```

[image]
¿Any idea? :S

Comment: I have read to JeanFrancois Arcand to "Check if you have a firewall or a an anti-virus that is closing/blocking the connection".
I tested by changing the port (from 8080 to 8484) but the problem persist
http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/Websocket-closes-unexpectedly-when-using-Tomcat-td4652803.html

Comment: Mule uses Jetty 8 (see: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.5.0/pom.xml#L150 ) Could this create an issue?

Comment: Thank you very much for you comment. 
I have tested again (outside Mule for isolation the problem) with the project in stand alone way and with the version of Jetty that Mule uses: Jetty 8.1.13.v20130916 and it also works.
I keep looking for a solution. If I find anything, I will post it

Comment: Show your Mule configuration, specify what Mule version you are using.

Comment: Hi David, my apologies for not having put anything here, but soon I will go on vacations and I'm closing other problems in the project. We have taken an alternative path for now. In September I will get back to it :) many, many thanks!

Comment: @AfterWorkGuinness Nope, we have deployed temporarily the Atmosphere project on Tomcat (here the project works) and connected it with the Mule services :S 
I expect at the end of the project we had time to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I could resolve this by setting `enableProtocol` to `false` in the request config.

In your case this would look like this:

```
var request = { url: 'http://myIP:8080/sc.eco/servlet/chat/',
            contentType : "application/json",
            logLevel : 'debug',
            transport : 'websocket' ,
            trackMessageLength : true,
            fallbackTransport: 'long-polling',
            enableProtocol: false };
```

I came to this solution was originally proposed in [this thread](http://atmosphere-framework.2306103.n4.nabble.com/request-onOpen-never-gets-called-after-upgrading-to-Atmosphere-Framework-2-0-4-and-jquery-atmosphere1-td4657501.html).